# How to drag views in graphical layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

In Eclipse when I try to drag views in graphical layout they don't move once draged they get back to their initial position. I am using LinearLayout for this and also tried Relative layout, also if any tutorial link for this topic.

Comment: You cannot drag views in the layout editor.  Android does not work that way.  Please learn how these layouts work and read about RelativeLayout layout_toTheRightOf etc, margins and padding.

Comment: I am a java programmer new to android please suggest me any good tutorial

Comment: On what @Simon said, you need to learn how to use the xml tab. It is much easier and more flexible then trying to do your `layouts` in the graphical view, IMO. I don't know any tutorials but you can search. All you need to know is basic xml structure and look at the docs and see what properties are available for the `layout` you are working with

Comment: Thanks a lot i will follow your instructions.